# Server times out when uploading file with Postman to Node js app(CURL works though)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, file-upload, busboy

I have a node js/Express app that handles file upload.When i upload the file with CURL it works fine.But when i try to upload with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) i get error status 503 service unavailable. In the server logs it says `H12 error Request timeout` which simply means the app took a while to respond(whether with status 200 or render json) to the request.It is explained [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout). I suspect the function that handle the file is taking a long time maybe?But again why CURL works and not Postman.Also i get the same behavior when i upload a file from another app.Can anybody guide me how to fix this?Thank you in advance.Here is my function to handle upload.

```
router.route('/images')    
.post (function(req, res) {

var fstream;
req.pipe(req.busboy);
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
    console.log("Uploading: " + (filename)); 
    fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/img/'+ filename);
    file.pipe(fstream);
    fstream.on('close', function () {
    res.status(200); //Seems like we don't reach this point that's why the server timesout
    res.json({ message: 'File uploaded' });
        
    });
   });
});
```

**Postman Generated code snippet**

```
POST /api/images HTTP/1.1
Host: myapp.herokuapp.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 31dbdf6f-7ff5-ad21-e42e-67b32f72b51c
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename=""
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

**UPDATE**

I just realized `req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename)` doesn't get called at all.What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I can help, but it's difficult to do so without knowing what settings you are using to upload the file on Postman. Without more details, we'll be guessing only at your problem.

Comment: I am sending a post request,with multipart/form data setting in postman and attach a jpeg file.